# Planning url rewrite for my web app

Tags: apache, web-applications, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a site which shows different products for different countries. The current url scheme I'm using is "index.php?country=US" for the main page, and "product.php?country=US&id=1234" to show a product from an specific country.

I'm planning now to implement url rewrite to use cleaner urls. The idea would be using each country as subdomain, and product id as a page. Something like this:

```
us.example.com/1234 -> product.php?country=US&id=1234
```

I have full control of my dns records and web server, and currently have set a * A record to point to my IP in order to receive *.example.com requests. This seems to work ok.

Now my question is what other things I'd need to take care of. Is it right to assume that just adding a .htaccess would be enough to handle all requests? Do I need to add VirtualHost to each subdomain I use as well? Would anything else be needed or avoided as well?

I'm basically trying to figure out what the simplest and correct way of designing this would be best.

Answer (score 0):

The data you need to process the country is already *in* the request URL (from the hostname). Moving this to a GET variable introduces additional complications (how do you deal with POSTs).

You don't need seperate vhosts unless the domains have different SSL certs.